# coloring df cell by it's value

Tags: python

I want to create a pandas dataframe that each cell is colored according to its value, meaning a large number will have a darker color than a small number. In addition, I want the top left and bottom right cells to be in green colors and the top right and bottom left cell- red. 
something like that:

[image]

the closest I manged to do is this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[16, 20], [5, 4]]))
color1 = sns.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
color2 = sns.light_palette("red", as_cmap=True)

df = df.style.background_gradient(cmap=color1, subset=pd.IndexSlice[[1,0], [1,0]]).background_gradient(
    cmap=color2, subset=pd.IndexSlice[1,0]).background_gradient(cmap=color2, subset=pd.IndexSlice[0, 1])
```

but it's coloring the top right and the bottom left cells in the same color and not gradient according to the value.

is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?